# How can I transfer downloaded games from my console to my friends and activate with my account

Tags: ps4, fifa-19

So let’s say I bought a ps4, bought fifa 19, red dead redemption 2 and Spider-Man on my psn account, downloaded the games on my console and can now play the games. And then I decide to transfer my games and other data to my friend who just got a ps4 console. If I sign out of my account and sign into his console to activate the games I had purchased with my psn account. Provided I do not go online with my own console, can I still play these games on the first console (mine)?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make your friend's PS4 the Primary one on your PSN account.
Do the following:

**First deactivate the system as Primary from your PS4:**

> Select  *(Settings)* > *[Account Management]* > *[Activate as Your Primary
>   PS4]* > *[Deactivate]* on an activated PS4 system.

**Then activate the system on your friend's PS4 as Primary on your PSN account:**

> To activate your system after you first sign in, select  *(Settings)* >
>   *[Account Management]* > *[Activate as Your Primary PS4]* > *[Activate]*.

The games you've bought will now be on your friend's PS4.